# Gigabyte Geforce GTX 560 Issues

Tags: drivers, nvidia, compatibility

I was unable to install Ubuntu via the graphical method. So i used the alternative text-based installation.  I am able to boot into Ubuntu now, but the display is squashed, pixelated and unreadable.

How can i get around this?, would installing the nvidia drivers fix this? and how would i install them with the display in this state?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that your answer is in this particular package:

```
ppa:ubuntu-x-swat/x-updates
```

I will try this when I get home, since I got the same graphics card

If you dont know how to add packages:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntu-x-swat/x-updates && sudo apt-get update      
sudo apt-get install nvidia-current && sudo apt-get install nvidia-settings
```

this should do the trick

Comment: problem is, even the terminal is squashed/unreadable.  So i cant really see what I'm typing or what output I'm getting.  Maybe there are some options i can add to grub from the grub boot loader so that i can at least see the terminal properly?

Comment: Yes, you can add `nomodeset`.